# Subset the sum and average of different columns based on the range of dates(may be duplicated dates) that can be combined into a month range

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how I can determine the SUM of Revenues for a month with date ranges that have multiple dates(they can be duplicate dates) coerced into an entire range of a month. I would like to follow the same process for Hours, and finally I would like to find the averages of the Index with relation to the range of an entire month. The goal would be to input the property name and as an output receive the total revenue, hours and average index per month for the property. It would be ideal to see all of the totals for every month presented within in the entire range of the dates available.

**Below is the data set presented**

```
Property  Date      Revenue    Hours   Index
Stanlist 7/12/12    878.67     38      7.26339  
Stanlist 7/12/12    647.56     28      7.26339  
Stanlist 7/13/12    345.24     83     7.86339   
Stanlist 7/14/12    838.48     45      8.26339  
Stanlist 7/14/12    153.56     89      8.26339  
Stanlist 7/15/12    877.34     12      9.26339  
Stanlist 7/15/12    848.57     78      9.26339  
Stanlist 8/12/13    329.24     39      6.26339  
Stanlist 8/12/13    656.77     39      6.26339  
Stanlist 8/13/13    478.45     38      9.86339  
Stanlist 12/14/13   784.56     78      8.26339  
Stanlist 12/14/13   866.76     67      8.26339  
Stanlist 12/15/13   648.46     78      7.56339  
Stanlist 3/15/14    569.34     39      8.26339
```

**The desired result...**

```
Property  Date      Revenue        Hours     Index
Stanlist 8/1/13     1003900.00     7384      6.26339    
Stanlist 9/1/13     89156.77       6374      6.26339    
Stanlist 10/1/13    73838.93       3894      9.86339    
Stanlist 11/1/13    927393.89      9732      8.26339    
Stanlist 12/1/13    67239.93       7383      8.26339     
Stanlist 3/1/14     74893.98       7484      7.56339    
Stanlist 4/1/14     89274.32       7484      8.26339
```

Comment: Does your desired results fits the data presented? If not, please fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid loops and use `data.table` instead (assuming `dat` is your data set)

```
dat$Date <- as.Date(paste0(format(strptime(as.character(dat$Date), "%m/%d/%y"), "%Y/%m"),"/1"))
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, list(Revenue = sum(Revenue),
                  Hours = sum(Hours),
                  Index = mean(Index)), by = list(Property, Date)]

#    Property       Date Revenue Hours    Index
# 1: Stanlist 2012-07-01 4589.42   373 8.206247
# 2: Stanlist 2013-08-01 1464.46   116 7.463390
# 3: Stanlist 2013-12-01 2299.78   223 8.030057
# 4: Stanlist 2014-03-01  569.34    39 8.263390
```

Comment: Thank you David and Robert! Both examples worked fantastic. David your example was a bit easier to replicate without having to reproduce any loops. You saved me a ton of extra work!

Answer (score 1):

First, I converted your data into an example

```
 df <- data.frame(Property = c("Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist", "Stanlist"), Date = c("7/12/12", "7/12/12", "7/13/12", "7/14/12", "7/14/12",  "7/15/12", "7/15/12", "8/12/13", "8/12/13", "8/13/13", "12/14/13","12/14/13", "12/15/13", "3/15/14"), Revenue = c(878.67, 647.56, 345.24, 838.48, 153.56, 877.34, 848.57, 329.24, 656.77, 478.45, 784.56, 866.76, 648.46, 569.34), Hours = c(38, 28, 83, 45, 89, 12, 78, 39, 39, 38, 78, 67, 78, 39), Index = c(7.26339,7.26339, 7.86339, 8.26339, 8.26339, 9.26339, 9.26339, 6.26339, 6.26339, 9.86339, 8.26339, 8.26339, 7.56339, 8.26339))
```

Next, we create a date identifier and a helper function

```
df_month <- strftime(strptime(df$Date, "%m/%e/%y"), "%m%Y") #  "072012" "072012" "072012" ...
stat     <- function(x, FUN) tapply(x, df_month, FUN = FUN)
month    <- function(x) strftime(strptime(x[1], "%m/%e/%y"), "%m/1/%y")
```

And our final data.frame:

```
out <- data.frame(mapply(stat, df, list(function(x) x[1], month, sum, sum, mean)),
                  row.names = NULL)

# Property     Date Revenue Hours            Index
# Stanlist  03/1/14  569.34    39          8.26339
# Stanlist  07/1/12 4589.42   373 8.20624714285714
# Stanlist  08/1/13 1464.46   116          7.46339
# Stanlist  12/1/13 2299.78   223 8.03005666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`. If `df`(taken from @Robert Krzyzanowski's example) is the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% 
mutate(ind=gsub("\\/.*\\/","/1/",Date))%>% #replace  values between `\..\` ie. `days` with `1`
group_by(Property,ind)%>% 
summarize(Revenue=sum(Revenue), Hours=sum(Hours), Index=mean(Index))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
#Groups: Property

#    Property     ind Revenue Hours    Index
#  1 Stanlist 12/1/13 2299.78   223 8.030057
#  2 Stanlist  3/1/14  569.34    39 8.263390
#  3 Stanlist  7/1/12 4589.42   373 8.206247
#  4 Stanlist  8/1/13 1464.46   116 7.463390
```